# Debugging an Electron application that uses Puppeteer using VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, electron, puppeteer

I am trying to debug an Electron application that uses Puppeteer, specifically setting a breakpoint in a public browser-side JavaScript file using VS Code. I've encountered a problem where my setup works fine outside of the debug configuration, but throws an error when using the --remote-debugging-port=9222 parameter as part of the debug configuration in launch.json. I get the following error: "The electron application is already listening on a port. Double `initialize`?"

I tried to change the debugging port but no luck.